# Using RF Link Transmitter/Receiver - ADC vs Microcontroller?

Tags: digital-logic, rf, analog, transmitter, receiver

I have a sensor that gives off 4 volts when actuated and I would like to transmit it a distance to a light.  So I found these RF Link Transmitter/Receiver at 434MHz:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10534
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10532

The data sheets and instructions I've read all suggest a microcontroller.  What I'm asking is this:

- For the transmitter side of my project (sensor that gives off 4V), could I use an Analog/Digital converter instead of a microcontroller to convert the 4V? Would the transmitter send that signal?
- I do have an Arduino Yun that I could use for the receiver side, but lets say I didn't have an Arduino, what would I be able to use to convert the data from the receiver? A Digital/Analog Converter?
- Last Question: Would I need multiple transmitters/receivers for multiple sensors?

Thank you for your attention and any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am assuming the is the same system you asked about in another question. I do not see anything in your system that is fundamentally analog. In practice the sensor has a yes/no output and the LED you need to light is either on or off.

Comment: Yes it is referring to my other question, in fact I should have credited you for finding the RF Link.  But the sensors give off 4V as a "yes" and 0V for a "no".  I didn't think the Transmitter would send that signal.

Comment: While it turns out not to be the problem you need to solve, simple schemes for transmitting analog values often use either a voltage-to-frequency converter, or a pulse-width modulator.  A serial output analog-to-digital converter can be used, but requires tricky synchronization logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FAN/RXWX/H3XMPCGC/FANRXWXH3XMPCGC.pdf) chip. It's intended to be used with a radio transmitter and receiver (detail to follow). The chip has 5 inputs all of which can be transmitted and received/decoded individually. You only need one input/output so this should be relatively straightforward.

I'd use them with radiometrix modules like [these](http://www.radiometrix.com/node/348) - they are called TX1 and RX1

You don't need to convert the 4V into a digital number - just regard the signal as being "on" or "off" and feed it into one of the 5 input pins on the TX2 encoder. The receiver/decoder has an output pin that will minic the sensor pin.